# Displaying data in JTextfield from two different mysql tables

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

Cheers everyone, beginner here!.

I'm currently working on a Java application to keep track of the inventory in our warehouse. It's all on localhost until it's finished. I've created two tables in MySQL database: one table shows the article code, location and quantity (VOORRAADSYSTEEM); the other table shows article code and description (STAMDATA).

In my GUI, I've got a JTable which loads data from VOORRAADSYSTEEM, and on mouseclickevent (getSelectedRow) shows the data in the corresponding JTextFields (so far so good). The only field not showing is the description field (which should be read from the STAMDATA table).

I've tried creating a method for this specific part of the program. The method runs a query to the second table using a inner join to the first table. Here's the code below.

```java
 private void LoadDescription() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ABEL?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
            String sql = "SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM VOORRAADSYSTEEM JOIN STAMDATA ON ARTICLECODE = ARTICLENUMBER WHERE ARTICLECODE="+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            pst.setString(2, sql);
            descriptionTxt.setText(rs.getString(sql));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

At this moment I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem. I'm also going to try using foreign keys. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reformatting your question so that it is easier to read your code would go a long way in getting people to help you.

Comment: @ck1221 Thanks for the tip! I wasn't quite sure on how to formulate my question

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to handle what you want to do. For instance you could get all the information you need with one query by joining the table on a common column (ARTICLENUMBER and ARTICLECODE) and then display it.

Right now it looks/sounds like you might be trying to get all the information with two queries.

However, there are some errors with your load description method:

```
private void LoadDescription() {
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ABEL?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
        String sql = "SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM VOORRAADSYSTEEM JOIN STAMDATA ON ARTICLECODE = ARTICLENUMBER WHERE ARTICLECODE="+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        ResultSet results = conn.createStatment().executeQuery(sql);

        if(results.next()) //make sure something was returned to avoid null pointer exception
            descriptionTxt.setText(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no results returned");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

This should work a little better for you.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll try it out tomorrow and will let you know how that turns out. The rs.getstring("description") is sure to make a huge difference, I reckon :)

Comment: I've tried the code you suggested and it does give me a better query. Thank you for that! I spoke with my boss about it today and she actually suggested the same thing you did, so I'll give that approach a try.